# How to plot a dictionary of sets in python?

Tags: python, list, plot, set

I have a dictionary of sets and I want to plot the histogram for it.
How can I do that? i tried turning it into lists but it still gives me errors linked to set

```
#Plot histogram for the first 10
keys = [key for key in frequency.keys()]
val = [value for value in frequency.values()]
values = list(val)
print(type(keys))
print(type(values))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(np.arange(len(keys)) - 0.2, [value[0] for value in values],
   width=0.2, color='b', align='center')
ax.bar(np.arange(len(keys)) + 0.2,
   [value[1] if len(value) == 2 else 0 for value in values],
   width=0.2, color='g', align='center')
ax.set_xticklabels(keys)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(keys)))
plt.show()
```

it give this error:
[image]

Comment: Please share your best attempts so far and explain exactly where you're getting stuck, or what error has you stumped. If people can have a look at the code, they'll be able to tell what problems you have already solved and what help is required. SO won't write your code for you, but it can help you write your own.

Comment: please look at my edited question. thank you for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says "'set' object is not subscriptable," which means you're trying to access an element of a set with an index, but a set is not an ordered data structure, so you cannot do that.

The problem lies in this line:
`val = [value for value in frequency.values()]`.You said you tried turning it into lists, but what you actually created is a list of sets.

So in line 9: `ax.bar(np.arange(len(keys)) - 0.2, [value[0] for value in values],` `value` is a set, so you cannot access its elements with `[]`.

To fix this error, do this: `val = [list(value) for value in frequency.values()]` -> this way you create a list of lists and then in line 9 you can use `value[0]`